# Creating a Notification Icon with Dojo 1.9

Tags: javascript, dojo

I want to create a notification icon with Dojo, but I'm not sure where to start.
The icon has to be similar to those found on Facebook and Whatsapp, showing how many new messages/notifications you have.

I've been looking in the Dojo reference, but couldn't find a good widget to use. Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but I might as well ask it here.

Googling hasn't been of much use unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there's no widget that automatically does the stuff for you. This problem is far too specific to provide a general widget for it. You also have to think about several things before you can start.

1. Do you want to use [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)? The web is generally made for pulling content, if you want to push your notifications from your server to your client, then you will need to look at [WebSockets](http://dojotoolkit.org/features/1.9/dojo-websocket). A good tutorial to use them can be found on [Sitepen](https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2012/11/05/dojo-websocket-with-amd/).
2. If you don't want to use websockets (you're not able to create a websocket server or you have some other reasons) then you will probably have to use a simple "REST service" and obtain the amount of notifications from it. This means you're script won't be "live", so you will need to pull the content from the webservice every X seconds/minutes. This means you need a normal AJAX request which can be done with the [dojo/request/script](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/request/script.html) module.
   If you need to time this AJAX request, you can use the [dojox/timing](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/timing.html) module.

This is only the "logic" part, the user interface (icon + # notifications) can be made by yourself with plain HTML and CSS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the logic part is not the problem. I just wondered if there was a known GUI implementation that would function well for this.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Like I told, the situation is far too specific to create a widget for it. Maybe you can find something in the DojoX library. I'm not sure if you will find a widget in the DojoX library and I don't recommend it either because in Dojo 2.0 the DojoX library will disappear. I recommend creating the widget by yourself, it's not a hard piece of HTML code I think.

Comment: I ended up using the following HTML/CSS3 example: http://www.icondeposit.com/code:pure-css3-message-button-with-notification

Answer (score 0):

What about dojox/mobile/Badge:

http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/mobile/Badge

?

Comment: Only problem is that it's from the `dojox/mobile` package which is intended to be used for mobile applications. I'm not sure how well this will integrate with normal web applications. Also it seems it's recommended to be used with other widgets like an `IconItem`. That means you need to use another mobile widget too.

Comment: dojox/mobile working fine on desktop as well. That said I agree you will start linking into several other mobile classes.

Answer (score 0):

From comment: 
"Maybe you can find something in the DojoX library" -
off course you will find much.

I would recommend

```
dojox/socket
```

see http://dojotoolkit.org/features/1.6/dojo-websocket

Comment: That comment was about the GUI part, I already told him about the websockets ;)